# Append to array by key if key matches javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm dealing with a real-time web application built in Javascript, more precisely, Nuxt JS. I'm using Socket.io which listens for data, and receives objects which contain an "agent", it could be a String, but for now is a number.

I'm trying to build up an array of "agents", and append each new received agent data into it's corresponding array item.

I figure I probably need to do some kind of grouping, and then checking, but not sure why my code isn't working.

```js
const servers = []

this.$echo.channel('agents').listen('AgentStats', (data) => {
  const agent = data.agent // agent contains an ID, which happens to be called "agent" and is a 4 digit numeric number, e.g: agent: 1010

  // structure to insert into servers
  const obj = {
    [agent.agent]: {
      agent: agent,
      history: []
    }
  }

  // push into the "history" array if this incoming request
  // matches an existing "key/agent ID" in the servers array
  // otherwise just push into the servers array
  //
  // TODO: this isn't pushing the agent into the history agent
  // if it already exists, for instance, "2222" appears twice
  // rather than the second instance getting appended to the
  // history array of that particular agent ID
  //
  if (servers[agent.agent] == agent.agent) {
    servers[agent.agent].history.push(obj)
    return
  }

  // push because it doesn't exist
  servers.push(obj)
  console.log(servers)

})

// expected outcome, an array of arrays where each "agent" is populated
// into the "key" if it matches
const servers = [
  '2222': [{
    agent: {
      agent: 2222,
      name: 'Robert',
      age: 18
    },
    history: [{
      agent: 2222,
      name: 'Robert',
      age: 18
    }, {
      agent: 2222,
      name: 'Jane',
      age: 20
    }]
  }],
  '3333': [{
    agent: {
      agent: 3333,
      name: 'Robert',
      age: 18
    },
    history: [{
      agent: 3333,
      name: 'Robert',
      age: 18
    }, {
      agent: 3333,
      name: 'Jane',
      age: 20
    }]
  }],
]
```

#### UPDATE:

I have created a reproduction on JS Fiddle to hopefully aid in explaining my situation further, see: https://jsfiddle.net/vqu5fp36/

Comment: Please give sample data of `data` , create [mre] and show current result, and current problem...

Comment: @ikiK I have created a JS Fiddle, with appropriate comments, and have updated the description of my original post to better reflect the changes, see: https://jsfiddle.net/vqu5fp36/